# Approximating the logarithm of the binomial coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients, approximation, factorial

We know that by using Stirling approximation:
$\log n! \approx n \log n$

So how to approximate $\log {m \choose n}$?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A better approximation for the logarithm of a factorial can be found by using $\log n! \approx n \log n - n$. Interestingly, the additional terms in the approximation of the binomial coefficient cancel out, and the result is the same as if you used the simpler approximation $\log n! \approx n\log n$:

$$\begin{align}
\log {n\choose m} & = \log \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!} \\
& = \log n! - \log m! - \log (n-m)! \\
& \approx n \log n - n - m \log m + m - (n-m) \log (n-m) + n-m \\
& = n \log n - m \log m - (n - m) \log (n-m)
\end{align}$$

An even better approximation uses more terms of Stirling's approximation, giving $\log n! \approx (n+\tfrac{1}{2})\log n - n + \tfrac{1}{2}\log 2\pi$ and hence

$$\begin{align}
\log {n\choose m} &\approx (n+\tfrac{1}{2})\log n - (m+\tfrac{1}{2})\log m - (n-m+\tfrac{1}{2})\log (n-m) - \tfrac{1}{2}\log 2\pi \\
& = n\log n - m \log m - (n-m)\log(n-m) + \cdots \\
& \qquad +\tfrac{1}{2} (\log n - \log m - \log (n-m) - \log 2\pi)
\end{align}$$

where the last term is the correction from using more terms of Stirling's approximation.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your second approximation correctly: did you use the ellipsis (“…”) to indicate continuation on the next line or are there actually terms missing (which is the only way I’ve seen it used before)? Anyway, given your name I’ll call this expansion the “Taylor series” in my code. That won’t confuse anybody at all.

Comment: It indicates line continuation. Glad that I'm able to introduce some extra confusion into your code :)

Answer (score 7):

Using $\log(n!) ≈ n \log(n)$ and the [definition of the binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Factorial_formula),
$\log{m \choose n} ≈ m \log{m} - (m-n) \log{(m-n)} - n \log{n}$.  The same should work for any of the more precise statements of [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Answer (score 4):

If you expand stirling's approximation for $n\choose\alpha n$, you may also notice that it can be written as 
$$\log{n\choose\alpha n} = n H(a) - \tfrac12\log(2\pi n\,\alpha(1-\alpha)) + O\left(\tfrac1n\right)$$,
where
$$H(a) = \alpha \log\tfrac1\alpha + (1 - \alpha) \log\tfrac1{1-\alpha}$$
is the binary entropy function (in nats).

If you further notice that $n\alpha(1-\alpha)$ is the variance of a binomial distribution, it becomes pretty easy to remember. (And you start to see how you might derive the central limit theorem for binomial distributions).

Answer (score 0):

The approximations in the other answers all require calculating logs for each approximation. Curiously, here is an approximation that does not require us to calculate logs for each approximation:

$\log\dbinom{n}{x}\approx 2n\left(\sqrt{p^2-\left(\frac{x}{n}-\frac12\right)^2}-q\right)$ where $p=\frac{1+\log^2 2}{4\log 2}\approx0.53396$ and $q=\frac{1-\log^2 2}{4\log 2}\approx0.18739$.

---

### Explanation

Let $f(x)=\dfrac12\log\dbinom{n}{x}$

$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\dfrac{n}{2}\log\left(\dfrac{n!}{x!(n-x)!}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\\
&\approx \dfrac{n}{2}\log\left(\dfrac{n^n}{x^x(n-x)^{n-x}}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\text{ by Stirling's approximation}\\
&=\dfrac{n}{2}\log\dfrac{n}{x^{\frac{x}{n}} (n-x)^{1-\frac{x}{n}}}\\
&=\dfrac{n}{2}\log\dfrac{\left(\frac{1}{\frac{x}{n}}-1\right)^\frac{x}{n}}{1-\frac{x}{n}}\\
\end{align}$

Shrink the graph of $f(x)$ both vertically and horizontally by a factor of $n$, to get:

$g(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}\log\dfrac{\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)^x}{1-x}$, whose graph is:

[image]

The graph of $g(x)$ is very close to the circle $\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+(y+q)^2=p^2$ where $q=\frac{1-\log^2 2}{4\log 2}$ and $p=\frac{1+\log^2 2}{4\log 2}$. Here are the two graphs together:

[image]

(As far as I know, there is no insightful reason why they are so similar; I guess it is just a coincidence. I discovered this similarity when I was playing with Pascal's triangle.)

The equation of the circle where $y\ge 0$ is $y=\sqrt{p^2-\left(x-\frac12\right)^2}-q$.

So if we take the graph of $y=\sqrt{p^2-\left(x-\frac12\right)^2}-q$ and stretch it both vertically and horizontally by factor $n$, we should get a close approximation of the graph of $f(x)$. That is,

$f(x)\approx n\left(\sqrt{p^2-\left(\frac{x}{n}-\frac12\right)^2}-q\right)$

$\therefore \log\dbinom{n}{x}=2f(x)\approx 2n\left(\sqrt{p^2-\left(\frac{x}{n}-\frac12\right)^2}-q\right)$.

---

### Testing my approximation

With $n=5000$, with my approximation, the average value of $\left|1-\dfrac{\text{approximation}}{\text{actual}}\right|$ for $1\le x \le 4999$ is $0.0169$.

My approximation is not as close as the approximation $\log\dbinom{n}{x}\approx n\log n-x \log x-(n-x)\log(n-x)$ given in the other answers (the corresponding average value for that is $0.00246$). But my approximation is pretty good for a log-free approximation.